# Program to temporarily disable/mask a few selected monitors without reorganizing the windows

Tags: windows, productivity, display, multi-monitor

I have many monitors connected to my laptop and I sometimes want to focus on just one or two monitor without being disturbed by the other monitors. I am looking for a program that can temporary disable a few selected monitors, e.g. it would blacken those monitors but it wouldn't reorganize the windows around as it would if I was disabling monitors using Windows settings:

[image]

I would prefer if the program supports Windows and is free.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [UltraMon](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/)'s mirror feature (Windows, non-free): it does not shuffle the window organization (i.e. after using it the same windows will be on the same monitors) but take 10-15 seconds to turn on/off so it's a pis-aller:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like Windows action center is complaining :P

Comment: @NickWilde Yep he doesn't like I don't use Windows update... no thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [Multiscreen Blank](http://nookkin.com/software/multiscreen-blank.ndoc):

- can be used for both private and commercial settings free of charge.
- work with Microsoft Windows 7 (I tried it), and perhaps other Microsoft Windows versions.
- GUI and CLI
- I find Multiscreen Blank 1.1.0 to be less buggy than  Multiscreen Blank 2.0.6, and prefer its GUI.

Multiscreen Blank 2.0.6:

[image]

Multiscreen Blank 1.1.0:

[image]