# Tool to disable part of an external display

Tags: osx, display

Sometimes I find the need to "turn off" part of a display I'm using. For example, I might move my laptop in front of the display to save space, and I no longer can see the bottom half of the external display. It would be nice if I could disable this part of the screen so that the experience of dragging windows is seamless.

It must:

- Support OS X Mavericks, and ideally Yosemite
- Allow me to disable a part of the screen, in such a way that the "usable" screen is still rectangular. Disable means:

  - Shows a black / flat-colored background on the disabled part of the screen.
  - Shows in System Preferences as a screen of the size I chose, so that I can arrange it properly.
- Be relatively easy to use. Command line solutions are perfectly fine
- Support displays over Thunderbolt with a VGA adapter.

Is there any software that will do this?

Comment: Related, for Windows: [Program to temporarily disable/mask a few selected monitors without reorganizing the windows](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/3430/903) (I really would love to find such a software, otherwise I'll just code it when time permits).

Comment: In a way, @Franck, but I want to selectively disable only part of an external display instead of the whole thing.

Comment: Yes indeed, that's even more advanced than what I'm looking for :)

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this?