# Program to 'spotlight' on a program

Tags: gratis, windows-7, display

Is there a program that allows me to dim the screen to only one program on my computer?

eg. If I am presenting something (not in full screen ;), dim the rest of the screen except for the selected window (in other words, 'spotlight' into the selected window)

I would like:

- it to be free
- do the above
- run on Windows 7 64 bit

Comment: Different, but close:  [Program to temporarily disable/mask a few selected monitors without reorganizing the windows](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/3430/903);  [Tool to disable part of an external display](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/9968/903)

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Yeah, they're all different but really close!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CinemaDrape](http://www.aurelify.com/cinemadrape/) and [Screenmask](http://sourceforge.net/projects/screenmask/) can be used to focus only on a particular area on a screen.

Comment: Please add details on the programs, for future users. I ended up using CinemaDrape

Answer (score 1):

[LeDimmer](https://sites.google.com/site/llemarie/ledimmer) is an app that lets you dim the area surrounding the active window on you screen.

**Features:**

- Very light weight ( 80 KB )
- Use very little RAM ( 732 KB )
- Instantly dims the surrounding environment when open
- Runs in the background and hides in system try
- It will automatically brighten and dim windows as the active window
  changes
- It works alongside F.lux
- It is portable and hence can be run from a USB drive also.
- Custom dark image can also be set for the background.

All the settings need to be applied through command line only. The default settings will meet the requirement for most users.

**C:\LeDimmer\LeDimmer.exe -alpha N(1-250)** changes background dimness value. 250 makes background completely black.

**C:\LeDimmer\LeDimmer.exe -image imagename.bmp**  can be used to set custom background image. Only .bmp images can be used

Comment: The question isn't about dimming the whole screen, just the area outside the active window.

Comment: No, I want to dim the rest of the screen, and focus on a part of it (like a spotlight)!

Comment: @ṧнʊß I have updated my answer.Please have a look.